# python json database corrupted

Tags: python, database, json

I got a bug in a huge database with thousand of lines, so i tried to remove thousands of them (obviously got a backup file) to lock out the problem and i end up with a problem. I'll provide a working without problem list in the database in case you want to compare:

```
#Working
["#saelyth", 8, 40, 4, "000", "000", "0", 11, "!Bot, me lees?", "legionanimenet", 0, "primermensajitodeesapersona"]

#Not working
["!anon7002", 545, 3166, 7, "000", "000", "0", 13, "\u2014\u00a1 Hijo! Estas calificaciones merecen una golpiza. \u2014\u00bf Verdad que si mam ...Vamos que yo se donde vive la maestra.", "legionanimenet", 0, "primermensajitodeesapersona"]
```

Causing this error:

```
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 240 - line 2 column 1 (char 239 - 366)
```

My question is: what is wrong there? i have no idea and all efforts to find what is the problem for json to give me such error are unsuccessful.

So i completely deleted that line and try to load the full database without that line but i also get now a new error:

```
ValueError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 62 (char 61)
```

With so maaany and maaany and maaany records like:

```
["tyjyu", 59, 302, 19, "000", "000", "0", 13, "holas", "legionanimenet", 0, "primermensajitodeesapersona"]
["inuyacha64", 15944, 79401, 3496, "000", "F00", "0", 16, "cuidence chau", "legionanimenet", 2, "primermensajitodeesapersona"]
["!anon3573", 24, 140, "1", "nada", "nada", "nada", "nada", "nada", "legionanimenet", 0, "primermensajitodeesapersona"]
["eldiaoscuro", 74, 446, 16, "603", "369", "4", 13, "nada", "legionanimenet", 0, "primermensajitodeesapersona"]
```

What would be an efficient way to FIND the missing , giving me that error? And if possible i'd like to know also if json got a maximum number of items to load or something like that.

**EDIT**
The code to load info is:

```
  data = []
  with open('listas\Estadisticas.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
      data_line = json.loads(line)
      if data_line[0] == user.name and data_line[9] == "legionanimenet": 
        data_line[1] = int(data_line[1])+int(palabrasdelafrase)
        data_line[2] = int(data_line[2])+int(letrasdelafrase)
        data_line[3] = int(data_line[3])+1
        data_line[4] = user.nameColor
        data_line[5] = user.fontColor
        data_line[6] = user.fontFace
        data_line[7] = user.fontSize
        data_line[11] = data_line[8]
        data_line[8] = message.body
        data_line[9] = "legionanimenet"
      data.append(data_line)
    f.seek(0)
    f.writelines(["%s\n" % json.dumps(i) for i in data])
    f.truncate()
```

I hope anyone can help me on that.

**EDIT2:** Python version is 3.3.2 IDLE

Comment: `print repr(data_line)` before you load it. May give you a hint as to what is wrong.

Comment: not working, using python 3.3.2 by the way. should i load it from a module first?

Comment: Well, then try `print(repr(data_line))`.

Comment: That syntax works, yeah, but... it did print nothing, same error. I added the print line after data_line = json.loads(line)

Comment: Uh, I said to add that line **before** you loaded it...

Comment: Wouldn't that give the ussual error of "referenced before stattement"?

Comment: Got it! since i am loading the file Twice i forgot it was loaded in a different section and with different name, not "data_line" but something else, got the prints and got where they stopped:P i'll update with info soon.

Comment: Found and fixed. it was a " in the string... i wonder how would i avoid that again. string replacement for " when saving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(repr(data_line))
```

before loading the file will print it UNTIL find the error. I thank @nneonneo for that